# Google search without any filter?

Tags: google-search

Google filters results by your preferences, but also by other factors such as your exact location, popularity, and others that I am not aware of (see [this TED talk](http://www.ted.com/talks/lang/eng/eli_pariser_beware_online_filter_bubbles.html)).

So I was wondering, is there an option or a special version of Google Search that gives a neutral result? In other words, the same results for the same query, regardless of the person/language/location/etc.

I suspect that this is impossible, as many of those criteria must be embedded in the search algorithms.

And if not, does a decent search engine with this feature exist?

Answer (score 8):

You may want to try [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/about.html) as an alternative. It doesn't filter and works pretty well, although I make no claims that it is as good as Google.